# VS2015 C++ redistributables are SOMETIMES not detected

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

We distribute VC++ redistributable files as part of our application -- they are at the same folder level as our app.   And 9 out of 10 times it just works.   However, sometimes, we encounter a customer on whose computer the redistributables are not getting picked up -- the app fails at start up.   And the fix seems to be to go into the client's computer and install the official msft C++ redistributable, and then things work.  The minimum Windows version our app runs on is Windows 7 -- not too ancient.  We have tried installing our app on a new Windows 7 image -- it just works.   Any ideas as to whats going on?  Thank you

Comment: Why are you installing the redistributable files at the same level as the app?  They typically go in windows\system32 or windows\syswow64.

Comment: dont want to disturb anything on the client's machine.

Comment: It's pretty standard practice to install them in that location. The install should update the path.

Comment: I would check to see if your problem customers are running Windows 7 RTM or Windows 7 Service Pack 1. VS 2015's C++ REDIST will _not_ install on Windows 7 RTM.

Answer (score 0):

If the application (or software) is big even without the Visual C++ Redistribute ignore this answer.
My suggestion is to compile with `/MT` instead of `/MD` a.k.a. use the static link libraries (LIB) instead of using dynamic link libraries (DLL).

Comment: Its a great idea, but we have a ton of DLLs.   So the runtime files would have to be a part of every DLL?   Its an old 32 bit app -- this would significantly add to the footprint, right?

Answer (score 0):

Universal CRT seems to have solved the issues we were having.  The number of files to be distributed seems to be rather large, but all of our troublesome machines seem to be working now.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt/